# obtaining first place in a competitive examination

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

How is the proper way in English to say that someone obtained first place, or was the first to be selected in a competitive exam.
I am trying to find the English equivalent for the French system where students have to go through a competitive examination to be accepted in a PhD contrat. At the end of the examination, the jury choses a few profiles among all the applicants and rank them. 
Thank you !

Comment: What's a *contrat*? Is that the word in French? What did you find using a translating dictionary? Why is "awarded first place" not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just saying *won?* Simpler is usually better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one would say "achieved the highest score" or "achieved top honor" in the competitive exam in question.